# Не могу разобраться как работать с linuxptp

Tags: linux, c

Два компьютера соединены Ethernet кабелем. На одном компьютере запущен master clock следующей командой:sudo ptp4l -i enx503eaab6d6ac -m -S
[image: Вывод]

На другом компе slave clock  организован следующим образом:ptp4l -s -S -i eth1(ничего не выводит)

В wireshark-е вижу, что пакеты ptp отправляются, но как понять, видит ли slave clock своего мастера? Ибо мне кажется что пакеты просто на интерфейс отправляются и теряются, как дать им знать друг о друге? Как убедиться, что slave и master обмениваются пакетами?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Запускать `wireshark` на обоих концах и смотреть.

Comment: @0andriy wireshark говорит лишь о принятии пакета на интерфейсе, вопрос стоит в том, видит ли slave принятый пакет, ибо от него ответа нет в wireshark